# Windows 10 update keeps breaking my graphics drivers whenever I reboot

Tags: windows-10, drivers

Every time I reboot my computer, Windows 10 corrupts my graphics drivers. I get the following popup and the display adapter drivers show errors in the Device Manager:
[image]

This has been happening for a couple of days now (3 including today?) -- here's a screenshot I captured when it first happened:
[image]

The Device Manager says both my graphics drivers (I assume on-board and dedicated) are toast, and if I try to update either one, I'm told I have the latest version installed. The first time I was able to roll back one, update that one, and it updated and fixed both of them, but I no longer have the option to roll back. What I've been doing since is uninstalling the 7800 series and then rebooting, which forces Windows to re-install it, fixing the issue. But after it's fixed, next time I reboot, same problem.

I'm thinking this is a problem with Windows Update, so I looked and found the following question about disabling Windows 10 driver updates: [How do I stop Windows 10 from updating my graphics driver?](https://superuser.com/questions/964475/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-updating-my-graphics-driver)

Is disabling driver updates, whether by disabling all of them (last answer to the question) or manually disabling just the installation of updates for my graphics drivers (first answer to the question) really the best way to solve this problem? They both seem like duct-taping over a serious problem instead of directly solving it, and I can only see that causing problems in the future after I've hidden the problem in the corner and pretended it didn't exist.

Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Version 1511 Build 10586.71

Comment: If you just disable the graphics driver updates, you can just use AMD's control panel to update.  If you want to re-enable them in the future, just watch for when M$ fixes this in Win10 then turn it back on, the manufacturer is always the better place to get drivers.

Comment: You can right click on those devices, choose to uninstall the driver, and at the sametime DELETE the driver itself.  That will help. AMD's CCC or whatever its called currently should be uninstalled first

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides a way of temporarily preventing Windows driver or update from reinstalling in Windows 10.

To temporarily prevent the driver or update from being reinstalled until a new driver or updated fix is available, a troubleshooter is available that provides a user interface for hiding and showing Windows Updates and drivers for Windows 10. You can obtain and run the "Show or hide updates" troubleshooter by downloading it from the Microsoft Download Center.

The following file is available for download from the Microsoft Download Center: `http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/2/F22D5FDB-59CD-4275-8C95-1BE17BF70B21/wushowhide.diagcab`

This will allow you to stop the download and hide it.

I agree that this is a bandaid fix, but there's really nothing you can do, other than submitting a bug fix to Microsoft / AMD about it.

Cand3r was right though, use the AMD control panel to update your graphics driver.