# Fujitsu NH532 USB 3.0 devices working at 2.0 speeds

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, usb-3

I have a [Fujitsu NH532 with 3 USB 3.0 ports](http://www.shopfujitsu.com/pdf/notebooks/LIFEBOOK-NH532-Notebook-datasheet.pdf) running Windows 8.1.

My problem is that none of the blue USB 3.0 ports is operating at 3.0 speed. Whichever USB 3.0 device I plug in, the Devices and Printers page in the Control Panel puts a remark that the "device would work faster if plugged into a 3.0 port".

All the latest Fujitsu drivers from their page are installed (it's using Intel USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller driver by Microsoft), latest BIOS version too, and looking at the Device Manager, I can see the USB Root Hub (xHCI) shown at the bottom, but with a couple of "Generic USB" hubs which seem to operate at 2.0. This is how the page looks like with a USB 3.0 flash drive plugged in (there are two Mass Storage devices, presumably the other one is just the built-in card reader).

[image: USB controllers]

When I plug in a device, I can find it in the properties for one the Generic USB Hubs at the top:

[image]

Note the "Hub is operating at high-speed" message.

[image]

On the other hand, properties for the xHCI hub don't show any tabs regarding connected devices:

[image]

Did anyone have a similar problem and found a way to resolve it?

**(Update)** - Added a snapshot of the devices sorted by connection, as suggested by @BenVoigt:

[image: Devices by connection]

This indeed shows that the USB 3.0 mass storage device is not connected under the eXtensible Host Controller.

Comment: "View Devices By Connection" is a lot more helpful for solving these sorts of problems than "View Devices by Type"

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the question.

Comment: Ensure that the device is plugged in the correct port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks :

1. The [NH532 drivers page](http://support.fujitsupc.com/CS/Portal/supportsearch.do?srch=DOWNLOADS&Series=N%20Series&Model=NH532&ProductType=Notebook%20PC) also has a USB Host Controller driver,
   while you are using the driver by Microsoft,
   so you haven't installed all the NH532 drivers.
2. Your USB device is on the Enhanced Host Controller, which means
   USB 2. As the NH532 has both USB 2 and USB 3 ports, ensure that you are
   using the right ports.
   Your device should be on the Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller.
3. Find in the BIOS (maybe under Advanced / USB Configuration)
   an entry that may be named something like "Intel xHCI Mode" and
   ensure it is enabled. Not all BIOS have such an option, but most do.
4. Go to Intel's [Drivers & Software page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/)
   and use "Automatically update your drivers" to get, install and use the
   Intel Driver Update Utility.
   This will get at least, if missing,
   the Intel(R) USB 3.0 Host Controller Switch Driver.

---

As according to the poster all the above conditions are correct on his computer,
and as the USB 3 device shows up as connected to the
*Enhanced Host Controller* - which serves USB 2,
rather than to the *Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller* - which serves USB 3,
I am led to the astonishing conclusion of a manufacturing error.

I have no other explanation than that during assembly of this computer,
the USB 3 ports were connected by mistake to the USB2 Host Controller,
so work at USB 2 speed, or that there is some other problem with the installed ports
or controller.
If that is the case, there is no software solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, unfortunately I tried them all, but no success. First link only appears to have USB drivers for Windows 7, not 8, do you think I should try those? Apart from that, yes, the laptop has 3 USB 3.0 ports and 1 USB 2.0/eSATA port, I am using the blue ones. There is an entry "USB 3.0 Controller" in my BIOS, set to Enabled. And the Intel update utility only updated the Intel graphics driver.

Comment: Since the USB3 device appears on the wrong USB Host Controller, is it possible that there was a manufacturing error with your computer - the USB3 ports were connected by mistake to the USB2 Host Controller?

Comment: Why don't you contact the manufacturar support?

Comment: @harrymc: I opened the laptop today and everything seems to be connected correctly as far as I can tell. There is a actually only a single USB 2.0 port on the opposite side of the laptop anyway, so I believe it would be hard to swap anything accidentally.

Comment: @Scorpion99: I tried contacting the support through the fujitsu site, but it's rather convoluted and I hoped someone else might have had a similar issue here. I might try again. Honestly, it's not such a young laptop anymore so there is not much support for it anyway. I also tried installing Windows 10 (which is supported) but it didn't help; and finally Windows 10 Anniversary edition isn't supported anymore according to the Fujitsu site.

Comment: Windows 10 has the best device-support of all Windows versions, so this strengthens the idea of a hardware manufacturing error, or simply that the materiel used is too old to correctly work with USB 3 or just uses an older USB protocol. Remark: I don't see any reason that the Anniversary edition will not work if Windows 10 worked already, Fujitsu site or not.

Comment: @harrymc: one issue (at least) is that the Anniversary edition installs a newer nVidia graphics driver, which crashes and the system cannot boot anymore. Probably there is a way to bootstrap an older driver and do some wizardry to prevent the automatic driver update afterwards, but I didn't want to go through all that. This driver is incompatible even if downloaded from the nVidia site, they just stopped supporting this model at some moment, but Windows doesn't seem to be aware of that.

Comment: To avoid installing driver updates for one device see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) of mine.