# BSOD - DRIVER_POWER_STATE_ERROR 0x0000009f ntoskrnl.exe - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod, ntoskrnl.exe

I have a problem with my laptop. I randomly get BSODs with the same error message. DRIVER_POWER_STATE_ERROR. Sometimes evey day, then none for weeks, but the problem really bothers me. I read a lot of posts here and there, and many people seem to have the same or a similar problem, but I never found a solution that worked for me.

Additionally I have problems with starting the laptop. I have the feeling it depends on whether the Power cable is plugged in or not. Usually it only takes about 10 seconds, but sometimes several minutes. When it gets stuck on the login screen plugging in or unplugging the power cable usually helps. I am pretty sure it's a driver problem.

Additionally I read somewhere, I should perform "sfc /scannow". It found some corrupted files which it could not repair. But I also read somewhere else that one should not worry about that too much. So, I'm lost here as well.

Now some hard facts:

- Lenovo Thinkpad T440p
- Windows 10

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Update: Here is the [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/17vqy6rvndwv5kx/AACobRdntugqbkgG2dCEKXhNa?dl=0) with

- original minidump dmp files from Windows
- output files from BlueScreenView
- CBS file connected to `sfc scannow`
- Analysis from WinDbg for one dmp file

Comment: You should use windbg to determine the cause of your BSOD.   You should post that information, once we have that information, we can help.

Comment: share the dmp and not this bluescreenview output crap

Comment: @Ramhound: I downloaded WinDgb. To be honest, I'm not sure what to do there, but I opended one dmp file with it and copied the debugger result to a text file. Does that help? I updated the link above.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I added the original dmp, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dump (`!irp` command with value from parameter 4 (ffffe001dbbf8c10)) shows that the `Synaptic Touchpad driver` causes the crash:

```
7: kd> !irp ffffe001dbbf8c10
Irp is active with 9 stacks 6 is current (= 0xffffe001dbbf8e48)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  Pending has been returned
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_WAIT_WAKE(0)]
            0  0 ffffe001d63a4640 00000000 fffff801a3d41ec0-00000000    
           \Driver\ACPI i8042prt!I8xPowerUpToD0Complete
            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe001d87de9f0 00000000 00000000-00000000    pending
           \Driver\i8042prt
            Args: 00051100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe001d76b2e20 00000000 fffff801a3e11060-00000000 Success Error Cancel pending
          *** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for SynTP.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for SynTP.sys
 \Driver\SynTP  kbdclass!KeyboardClassPowerComplete
            Args: 00051100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe001d8619cc0 00000000 fffff8023a51d418-ffffe001d5af5940 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\kbdclass nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00051100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]

Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\SynTP.sys
Image name: SynTP.sys
Timestamp:        Fri Apr 15 03:46:43 2016
```

The driver is relatively new April 2016), try to find a newer driver or install older drivers and [disable the automatic driver update](https://superuser.com/q/964475/174557).

Comment: Thanks for your replay, do you think it would help to disable the touchpad (and trackpoint) in BIOS? I'm using an external mouse anyway.

Comment: yeah, disable it, uninstall the driver and look what happens

Comment: any update? Does disabling the touchpad solve the crashes? if yes, click on the gree checkbox to "close" the question

Comment: no, that didn't help. Occasionally the BSOD still appears, but the newest "feature" of the thinkpad is that it hangs while loading the bios, you have to lift it up, and then it continues booting. So my guess is that there is a soldering defect on the board. And the BSOD is just the symptome of malfunctioning hardware.

Comment: ok, this is sad to hear. do you still have warranty?

Comment: yes, it stil had warranty. And they changed the keyboard and now it's working.