# Windows 10: Driver update prevention of USB removable device

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I tested the recommended [GUI procedure to prevent driver updates as shown in this howtogeek article.](http://www.howtogeek.com/263851/how-to-prevent-windows-from-automatically-updating-specific-drivers/)

I have a Prolific Serial-to-USB device, which requires the OEM 2008 driver.  The Microsoft driver circled in red does NOT work.

[image: Link to screenshot (click here)]

Although the procedure successfully prevents new drivers from being installed, it creates a new problem.   Tests show that it prevents the current OEM driver from loading when the device is plugged-in.  The device should show up under 'Ports'.  As shown below, the device has no driver and non-functional:

[image]

I feel that it is reasonable to 'protect' my device from driver updates and be able to load the OEM 2008 driver.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/964475/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-updating-my-graphics-driver