# Windows 10 Home: options to disable automatic driver updates for specific devices?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, drivers, bluetooth

**Problems:**

So far I have only found these solutions:

1. Disable updates for a specific hardware device using group policy - not an option in Windows Home)
2. Use of [a Microsoft troubleshooting tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930) - this didn't work for me as the update didn't appear in the list of updates available to hide
3. Disable all automatic driver updates - leaves me with a potentially unnecessarily vulnerable or buggy system

Is there some better approach to this problem?

**Background:**

I have a Lenovo Ideapad S400 (which originally came with Windows 8 Home).  The built-in bluetooth adaptor *DOES NOT* work with the "updated" driver package that Windows 10 insists on installing.  I am, instead, using the drivers for Windows 8 (from 2016) which *DO* work.

I want to keep using the old drivers for *ONLY* this device, but allow Windows to update drivers for other devices as it needs to.  Is this simply impossible without spending money to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro (or to replace my bluetooth adaptor)?

**References:**

Other people with the same problem in Windows:

[Disable automatic driver installation in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/954184/disable-automatic-driver-installation-in-windows-10)
[Disable automatic driver update for only one device in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1096937/disable-automatic-driver-update-for-only-one-device-in-windows-10)
[Can I prevent a driver from being installed with windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/665158/can-i-prevent-a-driver-from-being-installed-with-windows-8-1)
[Windows 10: Driver update prevention of USB removable device](https://superuser.com/questions/1104590/windows-10-driver-update-prevention-of-usb-removable-device)

Other people with the same problem with the same bluetooth chipset in the Ideapad S400:

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/3r4450/bluetooth_ar3012_and_windows_10_not_working/

Comment: See also [enable gpedit.msc (Group Policy) on Windows 10 Home devices](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/01/07/how-to-enable-gpedit-msc-group-policy-on-windows-10-home-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

First open Device manager and right click on the device. Then click Properties > Details tab. From the drop-down list choose Hardware Ids. Copy them all in notepad. Now open registry editor and go to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\DenyDeviceIDs`. Here create new string value named 1 and enter value as the first hardware ID. Create values in pattern 2,3,4,5 for next hardware IDs and as data enter the corresponding hardware IDs.

Hope that helps

[image]