# How to uninstall AMD driver that comes from Windows update?

Tags: drivers

Basically I want to install my own specific version that say, does not check the BIOS signature. However, it reverts back to something released by Microsoft. How do I uninstall the Microsoft AMD driver so I can install the driver straight from AMD?

Currently if I go to Device Manager, the computer said I have this driver: `21.19.134.1`. However, I want to install `whql-win10-64bit-radeon-software-crimson-16.9.1-sep13.exe` instead.

Is it the same driver? I don't think so. The date of the driver is different. The one installed say that the driver date is 9/7/2016 while the file name of the driver I want to install suggests that the driver that is 9/13/unspecified year.

Note: I did search in 21.19.134.1 and it seems as if it's the same driver as 16.9.1

However, I wasn't sure and there is no guarantee. There is no clear statement that 16.9.1 = 21.19.134.1

If anything, even if it were true, I would like some additional explanation. What is 16.9.1? What is 21.19.134.1? What is the driver's version? If 16.9.1 is the driver's version then what is 21.19.134.1 the driver's GPU version? The drivers woba woba version? What?

Comment: Googling 'driver 21.19.134.1' the first hit is a link for 16.9.1 - what research did you do already?

Comment: I did that. I would notice that in the question. However, there is no clear statement that 16.9.1 = 21.19.134.1

Comment: AMD's numbering scheme would be that 16.9.1 was a bug fix release in Sept 2016. 16-year 9-month 1-revision

Comment: So 16.9.1 is not the driver version. It's just the date the driver is released?

Comment: ATI used to publish a list of version numbers & all components. Unfortunately that stopped when AMD took over, so this is all that's left - http://developer.amd.com/resources/ccc-driver-details/

Comment: Got source? And can you turn that into an answer

Comment: Would you please turn that into an answer?

Comment: It's a very good answer

Comment: My only source is an unofficial list maintained by the support team of an online game I work for. It's done on an ad-hoc basis whenever anyone feels like updating it & is therefore incomplete. It also only includes the parts of the revision data applicable to that game - http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/ati For anything else, Google becomes the only reference.

Comment: Your reference is the best there is. If there is anything else it's not something I know off and not something anyone can find easily. Google? This page should be what google show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded
[whql-win10-64bit-radeon-software-crimson-16.9.1-sep13](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-Crimson-Edition-16-9-1-Release-Notes.aspx)
and have taken a look at the contained .INF file.
This contains the line :

```
DriverVer=09/07/2016, 21.19.134.1
```

So it is quite clear that **package** version 16.9.1 contains **driver**
21.19.134.1. It also contains other tools from various dates where each has
its own version number.

Once you find a driver that you like, you can block Windows from installing
updates to your device by using the procedure in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) of mine.