# PCI-E Sound Card not Appearing in Device Manager

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sound-card, audio-output

I have a [HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF](http://www8.hp.com/ca/en/ads/elite-products/elitedesk-800-sff.html) desktop computer running Windows 7 x64. The onboard sound card doesn't allow separate outputs for front and rear audio ports and they all output the same channel. I want to be able to use my speakers and have them connected to the rear audio panel and have my headset connected to the front audio panel with 2 separate sound outputs. The driver that comes with this computer doesn't allow separate outputs.

To fix this I bought an [ASUS Xonar DGX PCI-E](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B007TMZ1BK/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) sound card. When I plug this sound card into the motherboard it fits fine and the computer boots up. However in Device Manager I do not see the new sound card.

I have checked the BIOS settings and the PCI slot is enabled and I even tried disabling the onboard sound with no luck. I tried this sound card in two other HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF's and I ran into the same issue. I tried the card in a HP Compaq 6200 Pro SFF and it works just fine which tells me the card isn't defective. Upon trying several other HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF's this also tells me the PCI slot isn't defective.

I have also updated the BIOS to the latest version which didn't work and the other machines I tried had older versions of the BIOS which also didn't work.

**So what are my options?**

- I haven't tried booting a different operating system to see if it detects the card yet
- Could there be a BIOS setting that I am not seeing?
- Maybe the card isn't compatible with this machine?
- Could there be a jumper or cable that needs to be unplugged on the motherboard? One thing to note is when I unplug the cable from the motherboard for the front panel and plug it into the sound card the BIOS gives me an error upon boot saying "917 - Front Audio Not Connected" and I have to press F1.
- Is there a different sound driver that I can use that would allow 2 separate outputs for the rear and front audio ports?

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

The HP Compaq 6200 Pro SFF also has a Realtek onboard sound card that is a little older. The driver software that comes with that allows you to have separate audio outputs, unlike the newer driver that comes with the HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF.

The older drivers interface looks like this and it gives you this option whereas the newer one does not:

[image]

The newer Realtek audio driver is called DTS Audio Control Panel and it lacks the feature mentioned above in the Realtek HD Audio Manager.

Does anyone know of a way to use this older version of the driver? That would fix my problem and it would eliminate the need for a separate sound card.

Comment: Have you installed the [Asus drivers](https://www.asus.com/us/Sound-Cards/Xonar_DGX/HelpDesk_Download/)? And why can't you install the old Realtek driver? If the problem is to stop Windows from immediately updating it, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

Comment: Is it seated properly in the motherboard?  Perhaps you can remove it and blow some compressed air in the slot?

Comment: This is the type of thing a BIOS update can fix.  There's been 15 of them for your EliteDesk.  [Give it a try](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-elitedesk-800-g1-small-form-factor-pc/5387475/swItemId/vc-186570-1).