# built-in microphone not working for netbook et4007ew digma citi e401

Tags: windows-10, drivers, microphone

The built-in microphone was working fine. Then it stopped working, I check it using Voice Recorder app
[image]
There is no built-in mic in the recording devices list (just Bluetooth one):
[image]
I brought the netbook back to the seller. Then he restored windows to a default state (probably reinstalled) and microphone started to work again. Then in few days, it stopped working again.

I tried to use record voice using Jabra Bluetooth device. The windows allow recording with it. But when I listen what I have recorded I just hear the awful noisy hiss.

Back to the built-in microphone: I tried to install [drivers](http://digma.ru/support/download/?product_=2363#files) from the [official site](http://digma.ru/catalog/item/2363/)
[image]

Not sure in what folder exactly the microphone driver lives, I installed every single `inf` file from all the subdirectories like that:
[image]
Some installations showed success:
[image]

Some of them required reloading windows:
[image]
And a couple drivers just ignored my installation. No response at all.
Installing drivers one after another, I checked recording devices from time to time. And suddenly I see I have the microphone:
[image]
I check the recording, it works fine, I hear my voice. I thought that's it. But then I decided to reload the windows to check if the microphone gonna stand it. And unfortunately, I saw it was disappeared. I thought the driver somehow was dropped after restarting the windows. I tried to find the correct driver by installing all the drivers again. And checked recording devices after each driver installation. But haven't managed to see the microphone on the list.

So my question is how to fix the problem with the built 
-in microphone. Or at least please help me to determine what the correct driver for the microphone from that directory with all the drivers. How to do it?

By the way here is device manager:
[image]

I appreciate any comment that will help me to find the solution. Cheers!

## Update

I noticed the the microphone starts to work after reinstalling the drivers in directories:
`intcdaud.inf_amd64_12e2eb5912c0f66f` and `isstrtc.inf_amd64_185aeb11ade87280`.

[Preventing windows](https://superuser.com/a/1280575/195425) to update the drivers by hardware IDS didn't work for me. Thank you @harrymc anyway. For some reason, it was not blocking "bad" drivers. It was blocking "good" drivers to be installed after windows dropped microphone again.

So I disable [policy settings](https://superuser.com/a/1280575/195425) and reinstalled that 2 drivers again. The microphone works now. But it will probably be dropped again after windows reload (Not every windows reload drops the microphone, weird...). Then I will install that 2 drivers manually again. (But sometimes it doesn't work, I created windows restore point for this case in state when the mic worked) For now, I haven't found the way how to keep the driver and 100% survive after windows reload.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that Windows keeps on updating your microphone driver,
to the wrong version.

I would suggest to reset Windows to a working state, where the microphone 
works, then block driver updates to that device so it will keep on working
correctly.

For the procedure to follow, see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/964475/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-updating-my-graphics-driver/968749#968749)
of mine (do not follow the accepted answer on that post, since it is only
a temporary solution).

I would also suggest to backup the working microphone driver in
so that it could be reinstalled later on at need.
For a list of tools and their discussion, see the article
[Best Free Windows Driver Backup and Restore](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm).
After backup, test the restore to ensure that it works correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much, almost done, I [stuck](https://superuser.com/questions/1280600/lgpo-exe-import-error-no-mapping-between-account-names-and-security-ids-was-don) a little bit on `Device Installation`  in gpedit.msc

Comment: I added in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) a section for Windows Home. I also answered your other post with similar information.

Comment: Preventing windows to update the drivers by hardware IDS didn't work for me, added update to the question, thank you anyway

Comment: Some products do not survive a major Windows update and have to be reinstalled each time. If you have found the right drivers and so do not need to reset Windows, then you are all right. The driver update blocking should have worked - maybe since Windows wrongly identifies the device, you should also add the new Hardware IDs with the wrong driver - something to try on the next major Windows update.

Comment: although I haven't managed to solve my driver issue using this answer, it was nice to get acquainted with such option, releasing bounty...