# Permanently Disable HDMI audio

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, hdmi, gpu

After every GPU driver update my default audio device switches to HDMI, which I never use.

Is there a way to permanently disable HDMI audio interface from even being an option? 
Or, is there a way to set a permanent default, without having it reset during graphics driver updates?

Seen this happening with both Nvidia and AMD. Windows 10, but I suspect it's not W10-specific.

Comment: Have you tried to make the audio device you're actually using the default one?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yes, I usually set it as default for both audio and communication. And when other devices are disabled there's no more option (even greyed out) to set defaults.

Comment: You might try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) to block updates to the audio device, but it might not help if it's the GPU driver update that is the cause.

Comment: Open Device Manager and try to disable HDMI on the graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

There are two device groups of device:

- Sound, video and game controllers
- Audio inputs and outputs

I disabled the audio controller device:

(I'm sorry. My print screen is in Portuguese)
[image: print screen with device enable]

And the HDMI audio device has permanently disabled:

(I'm sorry. My print screen is in Portuguese)
[image: print screen with device disable]

My issue has been solved.