# Ctrl+Alt+Arrow shortcut doesn't work

Tags: graphics-card, display, hotkeys, intel-graphics, orientation

I have my screen in a manner that it is very easy to rotate, which is very practical to read. I used to use this hotkey combination in the past, but it seems that it is not working anymore.

I know I can change my screen orientation in the settings panel, but I liked this hotkey.

I have also checked my graphic settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) but I wasn't able to find this option.

Do you know if is this option disabled by default or something?

EDIT: I'm using Windows10

Comment: May I suggest you right-click on blank space in your Desktop, choose Display Settings, then confirm the default for Orientation is Landscape?

Comment: What is your Operating System? Please [edit] and add this essential information to your question.

Comment: Sorry, @DavidPostill forgot to mention. I'm on Windows10.

Comment: Hi @K7AAY, I'm currently on portrait mode, but I want to change it sometimes to landscape mode using hot keys

Comment: For diagnostic purposes only, if you go to Landscape mode, do Ctrl-Alt-LeftArrow and Ctrl-Alt-RightArrow work? Ctrl-Alt-UpArrow and Ctrl-Alt-DownArrow?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: That hotkey combination is usually specific to Intel graphics. If you use Nividia or AMD/Radeon they MAY have hotkeys & if so are probably different. I now see a tag mentioning Intel graphics, it's possibly the new Intel don't have hotkeys on by default or maybe support it. Can you clarify your graphics model?

Answer (score 1):

If the rotate option has disappeared in your configuration, it is probably
that the display driver does not support it any more.

If you have previously used rotate on the same hardware, then the only
solution is to downgrade to an old version of the display driver and
[block updates to it (Windows)](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

Once the option is working again, and if you are on Windows
and don't like the hoteky it provides,
you may either remap it using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/),
or use the old [iRotate utility](https://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm)
(if it still works on Windows 10).

Comment: The OP does not specify his OS.

Comment: @DavidPostill: True. I added a qualifier on the Windows-specific part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I'm not going to downgrade my video drivers, because I think it could leads to bigger problems

Comment: Not necessarily, but at least you now know what happened. You might wait for updates to the driver, in the hope that the option will return. You could also contact the Support of its manufacturer.