# Windows 10 - How to block a wifi network and restrict unblocking it without a password

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, command-line, blocking, netsh

## Background

I'm currently having some compulsive and addictive issues with using the internet (originally on my phone) that are seriously negatively affecting my life. I've completely blocked all web browsing and other such apps on my phone, which greatly improved my life. However since then, my habits have slowly adapted to simply use my laptop.

I've considered doing the same for my laptop that I did for my phone, however I'm pursuing a CS degree and use my laptop for school. I figure I could just rely on school computers, but that would be a pretty large inconvenience considering I live pretty far from the school.

I don't live alone and all of my problems only occur in private and so any method to force me to not use my laptop in private areas, such as in my room or bathroom, would be wonderful. (Also I can rely on another person to password restrict things for me.)

And just so people don't question my proposed method, I do see a counselor and he has told me that I should restrict my access to the internet and approves this method I've suggested. Its just how to accomplish this method with the technology is where I need help.

And I have an ASUS computer with Windows 10.

## My Proposed Solution

That was probably too much backstory, but anyways a solution I've thought of is to block my computer from connecting to the wifi network thereby forcing me to go to the middle of my house in order to use the internet via ethernet. If I could accomplish this, it would be a huge help and benefit to my life.

I know I can add a filter blocking the address by typing in the CMD:

```
netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="WiFi Network Name" networktype=infrastructure
```

However, I can easily reverse it by doing:

```
netsh wlan delete filter permission=block ssid="WiFi Network Name" networktype=infrastructure
```

Is it possible to password protect changing this filter?

Or is there an app out there that could accomplish this?

Any other ideas?

Also I've thought of somehow configuring the router to block my device, although I know a MAC address can be changed, so I'm not really sure how possible this idea would be.

Any other ideas or solutions would be super helpful thanks.

## Idea that won't work

I could have the wifi password changed without me knowing, but I don't really want to have to require everyone to keep the wifi password a secret since its always getting shared out loud with guests. I don't want to involve everyone I live with in this personal struggle of mine.

Comment: Please add the make and model of the router to your question, and not the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy the WiFi in a way that is not easily reversed, destroy its driver,
by either removing it or loading an incompatible driver.

Then disable Windows from updating the device using the method described in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

Comment: That's a great idea, although the only problem is that it will also disable the wifi at my school. I want to only block my home wifi.

Comment: It's hard to come up with an idea for something you can't easily undo. Can your home router let you ban your computer from wifi?