# Games won't display on primary monitor anymore

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am having an issue where it appears that the newest Nvidia driver is causing issues for me with multi-monitor setups in ANY game. If I run a game at 1920x1080 or lower resolution, it displays on my secondary monitor which natively runs at x1080. My primary is at 3840x2160. No matter how many times I select 'display 1' in whatever game or program I am using, it still uses the secondary monitor for some reason.

The only workarounds I have found are upping the display resolution or running the game in windowed mode (can't do fullscreen as it just defaults back to secondary monitor for no reason.)

Bonus issue: If I disable the display in Windows, or otherwise unplug it - any game I try to run afterwards doesn't work at all!

**So far I have tried:** Changing game from fullscreen to windowed - Doesn't work.
Forcing the game to use primary monitor by deleting values in said game's config - Doesn't work.
Unplugging or disabling secondary monitor - Doesn't work.

Is there any way to fix this issue so that I can get software to properly run on my primary monitor without changing the display resolution? This has really been bugging me and so far nothing has worked. Help?

I am running Windows 10 x64 Pro and have a Nvidia 980 GTX if that matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the existing driver, then try [this DCH driver](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/150584).

Comment: Thank you. However, this is already the driver I am currently using, I've already uninstalled and reinstalled, and this didn't seem to help. Odd

Comment: But were you using the DCH https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide version? There are two drivers out there with the same version number: DCH and non-DCH.

Comment: No idea, but thanks anyways! Seems updating my Nvidia driver fixed it, problem went away ! :)

Comment: ^^ Agreed! I updated and re-installed and this fixed it! Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 0):

If this is caused by the newest version of the driver, and didn't happen with
the previous one, then you could go back to that version.
If automatic updates to the graphics driver are a problem,
perhaps [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) can help.

For Steam games there is a workaround.
Unfortunately, Big Picture Mode needs to be used continuously for this to work.

1. Open Steam
2. Click *View > Big Picture Mode*
3. Click *Settings* (in Big Picture Mode)
4. Category Display, click *Resolution*
5. Set the "Target Monitor" to the right monitor.