# Built-in microphone not working with desktop apps on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firefox, microphone, audio-recording

My built-in microphone does not work in Firefox and Chrome (and other desktop apps) on Windows 10. I have used [an online microphone test tool](https://www.onlinemictest.com/) and have seen no reaction to loud noise during the test. Of course I had granted Firefox and Chrome access to my microphone.

The same test is successful on MS Edge (which is a UWP app) and also on other UWP apps such as the built-in microphone test tool and also Skype. Thereby, the UWP Skype worked, but Skype for desktop did not work.

The microphone worked fine for years; the problem occurred last week, presumably when I tried (under time pressure) to make a plug and play microphone work. I have confirmed that I selected the correct audio source (and have in fact only one microphone installed at the moment).

I have tried the Windows trouble shooter (no problem found), to remove and grant desktop apps access to the microphone, to update and reinstall the micropone driver, to use firefox in safe mode, and to scan the system for corrupt files. Now I am running out of ideas.

What could I try to make the microphone work with desktop apps?

[image: Here is a screenshot showing that Firefox has access to the microphone (sorry that I have this in German only...)]
[image: Microphone settings showing that FF and Chrome have access to the microphone]

**Edit:**

I have found out that reverting my audio driver to the last version (device manager -> Audio, video, and gamecontroller -> High Definition Audio Device -- right click -> properties -> driver -> earlier driver) solves the problem. I would be interested in how I can use the new driver without issues. However, I can also work with the older driver for now...

Comment: Screenshots of Firefox and Chrome interfaces showing the device is detectable would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the question. FF is in German. I hope you can interpret it correctly anyways. Otherwise let me know your question and I'll provide you with a translation.

Comment: I absolutely cannot read german.  I was looking for the internal interface within Firefox instead of a website anyways.

Comment: Hello. Does the windows sound recorder work? This is a windows app and should function. If it doesn't the issue lies elsewhere than your browser.

Comment: @NatsuKage - The author indicated Skype works.  Unless they are running the Desktop Skype client (unlikely since that isn't the default Skype client on Windows 10) it also is a UWP application.

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean with "internal interface within firefox"? The symbol at the top and the text in the speech bubble ("Mikrofon verwenden -- temporär erlaubt" --> "Use microphone -- allowed temporarily") should already give you a first hint.

Comment: @NatsuKage Yes, FF and Chrome appear in the list. I'll provide another screen shot.

Comment: I deleted my comment by error... Try deactivating them, restarting, and reactivating them?

Comment: @NatsuKage I have done this. No success.

Comment: Did you run the troubleshooter:  Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot. Select the “Recording Audio” troubleshooter, click “Run the Troubleshooter,”

Comment: @NatsuKage Yes, as indicated in the question.

Comment: Check in Device Manager the driver of the microphone, to see if this problem coincides with the installation of a new driver by Windows Update.

Comment: @harrymc I have reverted the driver to the last version and it works! I'll now see whether I can update it again. Thanks! This was a huge step forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poster has indicated that reverting the driver to the previous version has fixed
the problem. The explanation is that Windows Update has installed a bad driver
for the device, perhaps now incorrectly identifying the device.

If you wish to avoid future updates to the driver, see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672)
of mine, on blocking Windows Update from updating one particular device.

If the device works perfectly well with the old driver, you will not gain anything
from another driver
([link](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-it-aint-broke-dont-fix-it.html)).

Answer (score 0):

After a Windows update, the driver has been reset to the new version, and the problem occurred again. However, I have solved the issue:

The problem was caused by a noise cancellation option of the sound driver. Open the recordings tab in the sound settings (if needed, find instructions on how to get there [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/370220/how-to-set-up-and-test-microphones-in-windows-10/)) and open the properties of the device in question (right click -> properties). Open the tab "Improvements" (or similar - I do not have an English Windows version) and try disabling all the features. You may have to restart the computer before the changes take effect.

This solved the problem for me.