# DEVICE NOT MIGRATED

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth headset that I successfully paired with my laptop months ago, I stopped using them for about a month or so and in that time there was a Windows Update (suspected culprit), fast forward to last week, I tried to use the headset again - Nothing.

I see it under Bluetooth Settings as "Paired" but not "Connected" or the option to connect. So I Removed Device and attempted to re-pair but in the list of devices the headphone name had an extra letter added to the name and now it sees the device as a remote control(?)

Uninstalled/Reinstalled Bluetooth device from Device Manager - Nothing.
I opened the device properties of the headphones and noticed this:

**Device BTHENUM\Dev_CC988B3DC585\7&d4b3687&0&BluetoothDevice_CC988B3DC585 was not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match.
Last Device Instance Id: USB\VID_8087&PID_0AAA\5&418627f&0&14
Class Guid: {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}
Location Path:
Migration Rank: 0xF000FFFFFFFFF102
Present: false
Status: 0xC0000719**

Please, if anyone knows a fix for this I would greatly appreciate this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update has probably replaced your Bluetooth driver with a wrong driver.

According to the
[USB\VID_8087 - Intel Corp. | Device Hunt](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/8087),
the malfunctioning device is "Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)".

Create a System Restore point before starting, so to be able to roll Windows
back to the current state.

**Try 1 : Roll Back Driver**

I suggest first to open Device Manager, open the Bluetooth branch and identify
the device. Right-click it and select Properties. In the Driver tab,
click Roll Back Driver and see if the situation improves.
If the device now works, you may block future driver update by using
[this method](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

**Try 2 : Install the driver from Microsoft**

In the same Driver tab as above, click Uninstall Device to delete the device and
its driver. Reboot for Windows to install its own driver.

**Try 3 : Download Intel driver**

The device "Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)" is currently known as
[Intel Wireless-AC 9560](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/99446/intel-wireless-ac-9560.html).
You can find a driver for it in the page
[Downloads for Intel Wireless-AC 9560](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/99446/Intel-Wireless-AC-9560),
although it might be safer to use the option of
"Automatically update your drivers" for Intel to identify its own devices,
to avoid a mistake.