# Stylus writing on its own, very likely software related

Tags: windows-10, drivers, pen, stylus

I have an HP Laptop (Spectre X360 to be exact, from late 2015) with Windows 10 64-bit installed and a resistive stylus that is specifically made for that series of laptops.
Normally, if the tip of the stylus is brought closer to the screen, it acts as a cursor. In order to create input with it, one needs to touch it to the screen and apply some amount of pressure.

The problem is that from time to time, I get this weird problem with the stylus where it creates input without touching the screen whatsoever. I just hold it static without touching the screen (of course still close enough so the screen detects it) and it creates random lines, as if someone is shaking the pen superhumanly fast. In the video, you can see exactly what I am talking about - https://streamable.com/qgio08

This stylus came with no drivers or any kind of installation media.
So far, I have tried to "uninstall" the device from the device manager and restart the computer hoping it would fix it, none of which worked.
Interestingly enough, if I lock the computer with Win+L combination, it behaves normally there. So, at this point I am fairly positive that it is a software-related issue. But I have no software that could remotely be interfering with the stylus operation whatsoever. My touchscreen is also disabled and even if it didn't it should not be interfering with the stylus anyway since they work on different principles.

The only "fix" to this issue is either going back to the restore point I created earlier but this sometimes doesn't work either. Another way (which has always worked the few times I tried it) is "Resetting" the PC which removes all the software.

Am I right in assuming that there must be a certain folder somewhere that has files controlling stylus behaviour. My interaction with HP Tech Support was egregious as they stated firmly that there is no such folder, some agents even went so far as to claim that some device my neighbours may be using could interfere with the stylus.

For now the only option I have when this problem occurs is to reset windows apps and settings to defaul while keeping personal files. This means that I lose all the registries and the software that has to be installed to the *C:* drive
When I do reset Windows without deleting apps and settings, the problem persists. So far, a few times I reset Windows including the apps and settings the problem seems to be gone.
All of which to me suggests that this is not a problem with the stylus itself (as HP tech support would have liked me to believe)

I created a new local user account and tried the stylus behaviour there. Interestingly, inside OneNote it behaves normally, but outside of it it goes berserk again. It seems the pen "chooses" to "misbehave"s on certain settings...
So far that I have tried, there are a few "mediums" that pen starts acting normally. On the lock/welcome screen and the "Sticky Notes" app that comes with Windows 10.

In short, I am hoping to find the folder that contains files affecting stylus performance and reset that specifically instead of the whole system. Uninstalling the "HID Compliant Pen" with the "Device Manager" and restarting didn't help so far.

Update: I have reinstalled Windows 10 from scratch and the issue seems to be gone for now. I went to device Manager to check the version of the "HID Compliant Pen" and this is what I got:

**Device Provider: Microsoft**

**Driver Date: 21.06.2006**

**Driver Version: 10.0.10586.420**

**Digital Singer: Microsoft Windows**

But this was the version of Windows 10 that was a few years old. So, after upgrading it to the current version of Windows 10, the driver version changed to:

**Device Provider: Microsoft**

**Driver Date: 21.06.2006**

**Driver Version: 10.0.18362.1**

**Digital Singer: Microsoft Windows**

HP Customer service keeps telling me that there is no associated driver for this Pen, even though it picks up a different version through Windows Update. Is there a way to somehow acquire both of these drivers as an archive so I can manually load them when Windows Update messes it up? Till then, I will disable Windows Update just to be safe.

UPDATE: As of 06.09.2020, the problem came up again only 5 days after the fresh reinstall of Windows. I did pick up something new though. If the tip of the pen is pressed (it retracts when pressure is applied) without touching the screen, the pen starts to go into the crazy mode and jumps up and down. I speculated that maybe the tip of the pen is being blocked something and decided to clean both the screen and the tip of the pen with a 70% ethanol solution. After the restart, the problem seems to be gone. Hopefully for good this time.
Although this still doesn't explain how the problem was gone after the reinstall, I am glad that the pen is functional again.

Comment: There are BIOS and driver updates on [HP Support](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-spectre-x360-convertible-pc-series/7527520/model/7791778). Check well that they pertain to your model. They all seem quite old, except the BIOS which might be worth installing (very carefully and check its version against your installed version). You could also try to [calibrate the touch screen](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-calibrate-touch-enabled-display-windows-10).

Comment: Thank you, but I did update the BIOS driver to the latest one for the exact same model of my laptop from the HP website. In the meantime, you cannot even calibrate your screen with this issue since you are supposed to click on a certain area but you can't because it is jumping around.
Also, calibration is no excuse for this behaviour as far as I now.

The issue is gone now since I reinstalled windows completely, but I had to disable windows update since I am concerned that it will alter the "HID Compliant Pen" driver. Do you know how I can override Windows Update and use any driver I want?

Comment: Drawing and mousing are not dependent on distance from the screen, but on the mode and application the stylus is being used on. I have used active stylus' on various computers and they generally behave this way. That particular aspect of your question is based on misunderstanding.

Comment: music2myear, could you please elaborate what you mean?
When I said distance, I was referring to the distance at which the pen is detected. Even when the pen was malfunctioning, its rate of jumping was directly proportional to the distance of the tip from the screen. If I kept the tip of the pen at the maximum detectable distance from the screen (roughly a cm), it would go totally crazy. Once the tip touches the screen (although with minimal pressure, so it doesn't write), I can actually use the pen fine. But that is pretty uncomfortable making sure that I maintain that distance.

Answer (score 0):

As completely re-installing Windows and disabling Windows Update fixed the problem,
this means that Windows does not correctly identify the device and has installed
an incompatible driver for it.

A method for freezing the driver of one device only is detailed in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672)
of mine, by adding your device to the Local Computer Policy of
"Device Installation Restrictions".

After you disable updates to this device, you will be able to enable again
Windows Update. While doing so, I recommend ensuring that System Restore
is enabled and a system restore point is created,
so that in case of error, if the device driver is updated you can always
go back (if rolling back the driver in Device Manager will not be enough).

Comment: The thing is, even though the driver version has changed in Device manager, rolling back the driver option is greyed out, it also says that no files are associated with this drive. Unfortunately I realized that I could check the driver version after I reinstalled Windows from scratch. So, I do not know what the driver version was when the pen was going crazy.
In any case, I will look up your answer and implement that fix. Hopefully it will help my pen function while also letting Windows Update do its job.

Comment: Rolling back the driver in Device Manager is not always available, no idea why. This is why I always recommend System Restore.

Comment: Actually the last 3 years, System restorewas my go-to response. Every week I would check the pen and create a restore point named "the pen works". But the a few weeks ago. When the pen started "misbehaving" and restored the system using the latest point, this lasted a mere 2 days and the pen started going crazy again. But this time even the same restore point didn't help. That's when I decided to completely reinstall the OS. I genuinely hope that this problem won't come back now that I know what version of the driver the pen is working with.

Comment: This means that Windows installs a bad driver update, and I can help here. Restore again, then do for the device the procedure described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) of mine. This will block updates for the device. Prepare it in advance, to be sure that this method will work for this device.

Comment: I am sorry to say this but this problem reared its ugly head again. A few hours ago I re-enabled touchscreen because I needed it, and I can sense a mild version of that issue again. I checked the events section of both the touchscreen and the pen on "Device Manager" and the last 3 entries are from 5 days ago when I reinstalled the OS, with 3 entries saying the device was migrated, configured and started (with a second of difference in the entry).
Is there a way to *actually* diagnose this issue instead of doing something big and hoping it fixes the issue?

Comment: Has the device driver changed since 5 days ago, in spite its being in "Device Installation Restrictions"?

Comment: I haven't implemented the Device Installation restrictions yet but my Windows Update is still disabled and the Driver information is still the same: 

Driver Date: 21.06.2006
Driver Version: 10.0.18362.1

And the last event log in the events section is from 5 days ago, indicating the 3 entries I mentioned in my previous comment... I genuinely hope this has an explanation not standing on sorcery or something.

Comment: Another update, my pen's tip retracts under pressure, so just touching it to the screen without applying any force will just move the cursor. The cursor doesn't go crazy at all if I am touching the screen with minimal force, so I can slide the cursor without making a drawing input. But I just noticed that once I start moving away the tip of the pen, it starts to go crazy. Even more so if I press the tip of the pen not against the screen but with my other finger. In short, I cleaned both the screen and the tip of the pen and now the cursor moves incredibly smooth.

Comment: But why Windows reinstall fixed the issue even temporarily is still a mystery to me. I'll try and see if this "solution" sticks out for longer than a few days.

Comment: Perhaps there were two problems, driver & dirt?

Comment: Really doubt it, there hasn't been any significant change in the cleanliness of my screen this week. But in addition to cleaning the screen, before the restart I also installed "Intel Wireless Display" which was suggested by "HP Support Assistant". I'll wait a few weeks and see if this solution lasts or not, but given that this bothered me for almost 4 years, I am not really hopeful to be honest.

Comment: There aren't too many options here. If this isn't Windows, driver or dirt, then it must be some other problem with the hardware (computer or stylus).

Comment: At this point I can decisively rule out hardware. I have another pen from Dell that does the exact same thing when this problem arises. Add to this that maybe 5-10 times that I have done a fresh OS reinstall, the problem was always gone. 
But there is one question that I still can't find the answer to. What does manage the pen behaviour? Isn't there some sort of a folder somewhere in Windows directory that controls what the pen does? There is an HP Pen control app that controls the pen keys' behaviour but even without it those keys work, indicating that something has to manage how they act...

Comment: From all indications, this is rooted in how the basic Windows software works. There is also the possibility of interference from some installed software. If you want to check it out, a handy tool is [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) for easily turning startup programs both off and back on.

Comment: The interesting thing is, what could possibly get my pen to move randomly given that I have no stylus specific applications (apart from HP Pen Control) or anything that would remotely want to get the stylus to malfunction? I hoped that there was a way to determine what programs affect pen behavior and from there I could get rid of that trash of a program. From what it looks like, it is gonna be a mystery.