# DELL E5540 WIFI grayed out and airplane mode forcefully enabled after resetting OS

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, bios

so I have come across this problem where after I reset and reinstalled my OS on my laptop, the WiFi button has been greyed out or gets greyed out when clicking it, and the airplane mode button has been greyed out and is enabled.

What I tried:

- Install the provided drivers by DELL.
- Performing a full BIOS update.
- Contacting DELL(This didn't work because I was out of warranty and I do not want to pay anything).
  -Installing Windows 10 on an SSD.
- Disabling the airplane mode switch.
- Updating Windows 10.
  o) Resetting BIOS.

None of the above options worked for me.

My Observation:

One strange thing I noticed was with ubuntu, both Bluetooth and WiFi where working perfectly without any issues, so my guess is DELL has some driver that connects the hardware and OS properly due to their oddly designed BIOS, so the normal intel drivers wont do.

### EDIT

I noticed something new, so when installing windows again but this time 8.1, the WIFI was working, but after a restart, I was back to square 1. I have windows 10 right now.

Comment: Are you positive that Intel manufactures the BT/WIFI module in your device?  Does the air plane mode button within the action center look like [this](https://supportkb.dell.com/img/ka02R000000hFQeQAM/ka02R000000hFQeQAM_en_US_8.jpeg) by chance?

Comment: Have you installed [Dell Airplane Mode Switch Driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-e5540-laptop/drivers) by chance[?](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124347/resolving-not-being-able-to-turn-off-airplane-mode)  You can [edit] your question instead of submitting commentary.

Comment: i will try that right now

Comment: and yes, intell does make the card

Comment: its faills to install

Comment: What error does it give?  A log file is created that indicates the reason.  Do you have a device, listed under `Human Interface Devices` within Device Manager, named `Airplane Mode Switch Collection`?  You didn't mention if your action center looks like that image I linked to.

Comment: I had posted in my answer to check Device Manager for hardware errors. Do you see anything in Device Manager?

Comment: did you link to an image?

Comment: yes i see the network card in network and the switch working fine in human interface devices

Comment: @Xfaon - I am still waiting on the information I asked about.  Specifically, the one about action center and the device being listed in device manager.

Comment: oh one sec, ill post it as an edit

Comment: I have no log created, Also i tried again too and it did work, but the problem isnt fixed

Comment: and yes i do have that device showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the driver installed by Windows 10 is incorrect, you may:

- Install the
  [Dell driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-e5540-laptop/drivers)
  for WiFi
- Immediately apply
  [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672)
  to block all future updates to the WiFi device
- Reboot to check if the driver works and was not updated again.

If this does not help, it's possible that there is a hardware problem with the WiFi card.
Try an external WiFi adapter to verify this theory, while disabling the internal one.
If everything then works correctly, stay with this external adapter,
or replace the internal one (if physically possible).

Comment: they suggested i d that sinse i had bo warenty and follow what they said, i installed all the stuff they told me, chippset, not sure why that, but bluetooth, wifi

Comment: ima try an external adapter, but i also know another thing, changign the card made no difference