# I can't delete the driver software for my driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, internet

I'm having trouble connecting to my vpn so I think my wireless  adapter drivers are corrupt. I've had this problem before on a previous laptop, and reinstalling the wireless adapters drivers helped, provided the driver was deleted from the computer and the latest version from the computer manufacturer's website was installed.

So I need to uninstall and DELETE my wireless driver from my computer. It should not reinstall itself when I restart.

I can't delete the driver software for a driver from my computer. The delete checkbox is missing.

[image: delete driver software checkbox is missing]

Below is the expected behaviour of what should appear.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried finding the Atheros software in your Programs and Features dialog and uninstalling that?

Comment: Are you an Administrator on this machine?

Comment: Yes I am the administrator. There is no Atheors driver in Programs and Features but there is a `Realtek PCI-E Wireless LAN Driver`

Comment: No I'm not trying to delete the VMWare driver. I'm trying to delete the Atheros driver. The second screenshot was a representative example.

Comment: @desbest - That’s the problem with using examples....my bad

Comment: Did you try just uninstalling from the screen you showed? Uninstall should remove the driver so you can install another.

Comment: When I click uninstall then click "scan for hardware changes" it installs again. On Windows if a driver is uninstalled, it's technically not truly uninstalled as the driver leaves traces on the computer, which can cause corrupt drivers if the driver is installed again, even if device manager states "this driver is working properly" in the properties window. So it's important that these traces of the driver is gone from the computer, to prevent corrupt drivers and the only way to do that, is to also delete the driver, hence why I want the checkbox to be visible.

Comment: It may be installing from the Microsoft Catalog.  I have been stabbed by this before and had to wait for newer driver software.

Comment: It's not installing from Microsoft Catalog because it still re-installs the driver when flight mode is on.

Comment: I am going to guess you are running Windows 10 version 2004 or 20H2.  Microsoft changed how drivers are managed in newer revisions of Windows.  This basically means drivers  cannot be managed by device manager.  The option to delete the driver will not be offered when it’s a built-in driver.  We would need to know details of the driver to determine a solution

Comment: @desbest - Drivers are now installed through Windows Update.  What exactly is “flight mode on” you mean airplane mode?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, it's the same thing. Windows 10 however uses the term flight mode.

Comment: This might be a translation issue, official documentation, calls it airplane mode (nearly every OS in existence calls it that).  Check the Windows Update history for recent driver installs of that device in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please create a System Restore save point before doing any of the advice from below,
to be able to rollback to your current state in case of a problem.

The free
[Driver Store Explorer](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer)
can help to delete drivers:

- Run as Administrator
- Click on Enumerate
- Find the driver in the list and check-mark to select
- Select "Force deletion" and click on "Delete Package".

If Windows still updates the driver on reboot, you may prevent this by the method in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672)
before using Driver Store Explorer.
You could also try to immediately install your driver after running
Driver Store Explorer.

Comment: Where is the enumerate button? https://i.imgur.com/m3W6ES3.png

Comment: It seems like it was already done. Its purpose was to list all drivers.