# Windows taskbar position is reset on reboot

Tags: windows, taskbar

I have two monitors, one landscape (set as main display) and one portrait. I prefer to have the notification area on my left (portrait) monitor, so I drag the taskbar over to it to achieve that.

For a long time this state was saved by Windows over reboots, and the only thing that reset it was an Nvidia driver update. However recently it started resetting on every reboot/startup.

OS version: Windows 10 Pro, 10.0.19041

If it was working:

- The portrait display (extended display) should have the main task bar.
- The landscape display (main display) should not have the main task bar.

**Update:**
When Windows starts up and is at the login screen, I hear the `device connection` sound you hear when you plug in a device. The screen flashes before coming back on. I've noticed after many restarts that the only time the taskbar position remains on the portrait display is when this sound/flash does NOT happen.

So far I've been unable to determine what causes the screen to flash/the connection sound to be made. Both monitors are on during any boot/restart process, and neither appear to be asleep in any way as the time from boot to login is quite short.

Comment: Which display is Primary?

Comment: If you switch the video cables and/or ports on the GPU (I assume they are the same) does the behavior change?  What is happening is a sign the display is not enabled at the time Windows goes to assign displays.  This is probably happening well before you even see the Windows logon.

Comment: @Ramhound that's interesting, it is completely possible I'm leaving it at Windows login long enough that my extended display is turning off. I'll try that.

Comment: Do you have any apps that modify Windows look (ex: Stardock)? Maybe that is resetting. Analyze keys here on fresh boot compared to AFTER you move taskbar: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` (Group Policy: _User Configuration\ Administrative Templates\ Start Menu and taskbar\Lock all taskbar settings_). SW might be changing it here, [sysinternals procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) can help isolate WHAT is changing that registry thus causing

Comment: @gregg I don't believe so. I'm using Power Toys (Fancy Zones), not sure if it would touch anything Taskbar related. The only key at that location after a boot and moving the Taskbar is: NoDriveTypeAutoRun.

Comment: Did try right-click on the taskbar and select "Lock all taskbars"?

Comment: @harrymc yeah I also tried locking it from group policy as suggested above - in both cases it still moved back to the main monitor after a reboot.

Comment: Try perhaps this [registry hack](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/105189-enable-disable-taskbar-settings-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: ... Also, questions: Do you have a third-party toolbar in the taskbar? If boot and reboot in Safe mode does the taskbar stay in its place?

Comment: @harrymc I use PowerToys for Windows - which does start (on startup) and had every feature enabled. Few of them affect explorer/layout, but FancyZones does. I'm currently trying to test whether this is the culprit, or if RGDIX7's suggestion is the winner here.

Comment: Power Toys ended up not being the culprit (uninstalled it altogether. Still searching for the cause.

Comment: What cables do you use for the monitors? Is the problem on a monitor connected via DisplayPort?

Comment: @harrymc Yeah display port cables for both monitors.

Comment: That's a big hint, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two facts, that you hear the `device connection` sound and that the monitors
are connected via DisplayPort, is a big hint.

DisplayPort ports under Windows are implemented differently
than VGA and DVI ports, in that when they enter the sleep state Windows
treats them as if they were removed, even displacing their displayed windows
to other monitors. When the monitor wakes up, Windows treats it as a new device
being discovered. This behavior might be the cause of your problems.

It seems like Windows, when starting, discovers the DisplayPort monitors at a
later stage of the boot than before, therefore treating them as new monitors.
Specifically, the taskbar is not installed on the monitor, since it is not
available at that time.

I don't know what caused that change. It might be a change in Windows,
or a new monitor driver (this is something that you may check).

If you don't find out what has changed, you will need to change your setup,
perhaps defining the other monitor as primary, or finding out how to automate
the moving of the taskbar upon boot to the secondary monitor
(the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) may help here).

Comment: I believe this is exactly what the problem is. As for how to solve it - that's another matter. I'll dig in and if I come up with something I'll comment here.

Comment: If it comes down to blocking Windows from updating a driver, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

Comment: Just an update but I never actually figured out how to resolve this. I'm kind of living with it for the moment and hoping some combination of windows update or nvidia driver update fixes it. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

**Are you using more than one Language within Windows?**

Using mutltiple keyboard with [Shift]+[Alt] and it's keyboard settings have produced this error for me in the past.

Removing any other Keyboard layout than the native one did the trick for me.

Nothin special, but maybe this helps.

Cheers

Comment: I did have an extra language set in windows, which was partially attributed to the keyboard/desktop. I had the switcher turned off (and the hotkeys removed). So I'm not sure if removing it was the fix - or if it was something else I did. But this seems like a possible reason.

Comment: Update: this didn't solve it after all. Still trying to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but I think what you want is for the Taskbar to remain on the same monitor after reboot and don't want the taskbar to be on any other monitor.

There is a settings that will allow you to make a monitor your main display.

1. Start -> Settings (gear icon) -> System -> Display.
2. Select the monitor you wish to make your main display. (The monitor you want the task bar to be on)
3. On the bottom, in the "Mulitple displays" area, put a check mark in "Make this my main display"
   [image]

Next, need to change the task bar settings

5. Start -> Settings -> Personalization -> Taskbar
6. On the bottom, in the "Multiple displays" area, turn off "Show taskbar on all displays"
   [image]

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had taskbar related problems before. To mitigate that, I had to make a new user account - it worked. Try making a new user account and see if it's okay in the new account. If all's well, then move your files to it and delete your old account.

To make a new account, click `Win`+`I`. It should open `Settings`. Now go to `Accounts`

[image: Settings]

After that, go to `Family & Other Users` (from the sidebar)

[image: Settings]

Now, in the `Other Users` section, click `Add someone else to this PC`

[image: Settings]

If you have a second Microsoft account, log in using that. If not, then make a local account for now (You can log in using a Microsoft account later). To do that, click `I don't have this person's sign-in info` After that, click `Add a user without a Microsoft account`

[image: Settings]

[image: Settings]

After that, enter an username and password and proceed. You now have a second account. Log into that and see if the problem persists

Comment: I actually tried this as well - I'm on a completely new user profile. After transferring all my stuff over the problem persisted. Good idea though.