# How to completely and eternally remove Realtek audio driver from Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, drivers

I hate the Realtek audio driver like no one has ever hated a driver before. Constant popping and clicking throughout the day and night, and constant nagging questions about whether I'm plugging in speakers or headphones-- and if so, which *size* of speakers or headphones. I **hate** it. I want to be rid of it. Forever.

The problem is that the driver keeps coming back. I disable it, uninstall it, and it comes right back. I even edited the registry on the suggestion of a few other users, but days later, the Realtek driver came back.

There was a brief 48-72 hr period where I was able to enable and use a basic "HD audio" driver (which I assume was a bare-bones Windows 10 audio driver), and it was glorious. No popping, no clicking, and no asking me questions every time I plugged in a 3.5mm jack. I could listen to music like it was the 1990s and I was using Windows 3.1 with some wired speakers.

Now, I've been shaken back to the dystopian future nightmare of 2021 and the Realtek virus, and all my audio problems are back.

Can anyone tell me how to *completely* and *totally* rid my life of this annoying Realtek driver?

Comment: There is no "bare bones" or generic audio driver in Windows except for some USB devices. One way or the other you were using an included Realtek driver, likely not up-to-date, and installed automatically by Windows whenever it detects the audio device. The only way to not have a driver is to disable the audio chipset, something you obviously don't want. **I think what you want is to have the Realtek driver but not the companion software.** I'n far from an expert in Windows but I suspect there's a better way.

Comment: Disable the sound driver and install a quality usb (laptop) or internal (desktop) sound card

Comment: If you continue to use that sound source and somehow disable their junk, you will not be able to switch between headphones, headset, speaker without their s**t software.  As far as I am aware, there is no generic solution for this.  The fact that you mention the popup crap tells me that you use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that to achieve a 48-72 hr using the "HD audio" driver, you have deleted
the driver in some way, but that the Realtek audio driver was installed again
automatically by Windows.

If you can repeat that achievement, you can also block Windows from again
updating the driver, in effect freezing the device with its "HD audio" driver.

For that, see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672)
of mine. It's in a post that's about the graphics driver, but will work
with any device.