# Uninstalling a hidden driver

Tags: drivers, acer-aspire, windows-11, hid

After upgrading to Windows 11 I have a problem with the volume and brightness keyboard shortcuts not working. I figured that it was a driver from Acer. I don't remember the exact name, nor did I take any note of the hardware ID. I removed it, and the problem seemed to go away.

After a few days, Windows Update has decided to reinstall the driver and once again, the keyboard shortcuts no longer work. Even more interesting this time, I can no longer see them on the Device Manager even with "show hidden devices" on.

The driver was listed as `Acer Incorporated - HIDClass - 4/6/2017 12:00:00 AM - 8.0.0.3` on the update history. I looked up for "HIDClass" using DriverView, a third party tool and apparently it was a driver made by Microsoft, not Acer.

I tried sorting the drivers from their install/last modified date and I couldn't find anything that seems to be related and modified today, so how do I get rid of this "hidden" driver?

As a note I also used `wushowhide.diagcab` after this mess happened so this doesn't happen again in the future. However I need to remove it now, somehow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop Windows 10 from updating my graphics driver?](https://superuser.com/questions/964475/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-updating-my-graphics-driver) Especially [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

Comment: If Windows reinstalls the driver from the Driver Update Catalogue no matter what, then you need to contact Acer Support. I had that with an Intel Driver and Intel Support solved the issue.

Comment: @John: My linked answer shows how to prevent Windows from updating the driver of a specific device.

Comment: I have seen drivers obey the way to prevent driver updates and not obey the way to prevent driver updates. There is not a one size fits all - preventing driver updates may or may not work.