# What would prevent an OEM audio device driver from installing?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, realtek-hd-audio

I maintain a cluster of HP XW8600 servers for CAD and Mathematica users - all running Windows 7.

Additionally, all are using the onboard Realtek Audio chipset with the latest driver (6.0.1.5973) from the HP web site. On one workstation, I installed a new Nvidia graphics card and it installed an audio driver at the same time as the graphics driver. It completely broke the audio so I backed out the Nvidia install and reinstalled the Realtek High Definition Audio Driver (sp46836.exe).

The install appears to run fine, however, upon reboot the Microsoft Audio Driver is installed and not the Realtek - and the Microsoft driver does not provide any sound. I have tried showing hidden devices and drivers but to no avail. I have tried uninstalling the Microsoft driver but it returns upon the next hardware scan.  I have also tried disabling the Microsoft driver.

On the other workstations I also see a Realtek HD Audio Manager icon in the Control Panel. There is nothing on this one.

So, something is blocking the install or the running of the driver.  I see the full set of software in: `C:\Progam Files (x86)\Realtek\`.

I am considering amending the .ini file to point to a log file but unsure of the correct syntax.

Comment: What does event viewer say? Have you looked up logging in the installer?

Comment: Unfortunately, EV logs contain nothing helpful.  Just the usual chatter one expects to see.  I have not checked the installer log.  Would that be in the folder where the install unzips and runs - or is there another location?   My core competency is Linux, hence the question.

Comment: I dug into the install directory and there are no log files or any files touched since it was unpacked.  I tried running it from the command line but no messages to STDOUT.  This is becoming a real stumper.

Comment: Lack of an answer has motivated me to share my experience.  I made a mistake and removed whatever component of RealTek makes the headphone choice popup when plugged in (two years ago).  After installing "the latest" driver, the problem still wasn't solved.  I fought the same thing you are dealing with and I can't tell you which of the million things I tried actually solved the problem.  Why am I talking then??  Because I want you to know that if you screw with it long enough, it is solvable and you will figure it out.

Comment: This being a server, I don't suppose that System Restore was enabled and could be used here? Have you tried to delete the audio device and its driver and reboot?

Comment: Note: You should not use Windows 7 anymore as it is end of life software and has not received updates since January 2021

Comment: I appreciate the answers.  I will have one more final go at resolving this tomorrow to be fair to everyone who participated and before the bounty expires.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with a Win7 machine and an Nvidia card. I had to uninstall the Nvidia card, use Revo uninstall to get rid of all the Nvidia stuff, reboot and then use CCleaner to do its basic cleanup. Rebooted and reinstalled the Realtek driver. Made sure it was working properly, then reinstalled the Nvidia card. Made sure to check"custom install" on the driver to make sure the Nvidia driver parts were not installed.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try.  I did 90% of that but I did not try Revo uninstall.   There was nothing in System Restore so that was not an option either.

Comment: I followed this exactly and no success.  CCleaner removed lots of registry entries.  sfc /scannow showed no issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that Windows insists on updating the driver to
a version that it considers is better than Realtek for your device.

I would suggest to:

- Remove in Device Manager the Realtek Audio chipset device with
  its driver, but do not reboot yet.
- Block all driver updates to the device by the procedure
  described in
  [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).
  Note that the step of retrieving the device hardware ID
  is to be done before you delete the device as above.
- Install the Realtek driver.
- Reboot to check that the device works with the correct driver.
  If the Realtek driver has not been automatically used, you will need
  to install it manually.

Comment: I like this approach.  However, the Realtek driver does not install if the device is blocked as per the link.  Even a manual install failed with the block in place.  Without the block, the software portion installs (C:/ProgramFiles/Realtek) but the driver does not install.  I am going to copy the driver files from one workstation and point the "Update Driver" to them and see if it works.

Comment: @Notamachine: Did it succeed?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.   I tried about 8 different permutations with no joy.

Comment: Try to reinstall while booting in Safe mode.