# AMD graphics driver keeps reverting to default one

Tags: drivers, amd-radeon, integrated-graphics

I have a Dell Inspiron 3500 with Windows 11 OS, with AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx, 2100 Mhz, 4 Cores, 8 Logical Processors. I botched up my laptop somehow, and had to do a reset, and since then this keeps happening.

If I install the AMD Ryzen 5 3500U graphics driver via
[the AMD website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/apu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-5-mobile-processors-radeon-vega-graphics/amd-ryzen-5-3500u), it installs perfectly and works for a few hours or until I restart my computer. Then the graphics driver reverts to "AMD Radeon Graphics" driver instead of "AMD Radeon Vega 8 Graphics Gfx" (I think that's correct), i.e. the one I just installed.

I have tried uninstalling/deleting everything to do with AMD and I've tried using DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) and the AMD Cleaner too, both in safe both, and it still reverts. I also have automatic driver updates from Windows Update off. I've also tried using the group policy too, and it still reverts.

Is there a way to stop my graphics driver from reverting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop Windows 10 from updating my graphics driver?](https://superuser.com/questions/964475/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-updating-my-graphics-driver) See especially [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

Comment: @harrymc, sadly no. This solution provided mentions Windows Update and the Group Policy Editor and the Registry Editor. All of these, I have tried already.

Comment: This is not the same, try it.

Comment: @harrymc, yeah, it is, it's gpedit.msc / Group Policy Editor, tried it already.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

If I install the "Auto-Detect and Install Driver Updates for AMD Radeon™ Series Graphics and Ryzen™ Chipsets", this fixes all issues. The graphics driver doesn't revert back any more.

The Auto-Detect tool can be found at: https://www.amd.com/en/support

Comment: Two points: (1) You should accept your answer if it fixed your problem (2) it seems the service "AMD Crash Defender Service" (c:\windows\system32\amdfendrsr.exe) is responsible for resetting; maybe disabling the service also fixes that.