# Windows won't remember video settings/driver after reboot

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

Problem: Windows always starts in low resolution, changing to the correct resolution after some seconds. Windows is not remembering the correct resolution/driver.
I don't know how to fix this but reinstalling Windows (update: also didn't work). Any suggestions?

What I did:

- Uninstalled video drivers using [DDU v18];
- Clean install during NVIDIA driver installer;
- Disabled the processor built-in GPU in Device manager.
- Fresh Windows 10 Pro install. Solved it for a couple of days only.

Setup:

- Mobo: STRIX Z370-E;
- GPU: GeForce RTX 2070;
- GPU "2": Intel's UHD Graphics 630 IGP (Intel i7 8700k);
- OS: Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) to block Windows from updating the video driver. Which video driver version is currently installed?

Comment: Latest NVIDIA driver: 527.56. I'll try.

Comment: by 'start' in your case did you mean windows starts in low resolution when turning on the computer? or that it goes to the desktop and everything with the low resolution?  if it turns on and then it shows the problems it could be a bug in the driver, nor uninstalling it or doing a clean install wont work, as it reinstalls the same version of driver with the error.  probably downgrading the driver will help get rid of bugs.

Comment: You can stop the driver from being updated.  I had asked this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/964475/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-updating-my-graphics-driver) and I would recommend the answer by harrymc.  As much as I would like the bounty, I cant copy paste it :-)

Comment: I suspect one of two things: 1)Win update is unhelpfully updating your driver to different buggy version or WDDM version which you may need to disable somewhere. After you do a fresh install of Windows note the driver version. Upgrade then note the driver version. When issue recurs note the driver version. Device Manager, display adapter right-click properties, Events tab can show when drivers get installed. 2)an app, service, something in startup may be CHANGING the resolution unbeknownst to you...after fresh install apps or changes things then reboot after each to confirm if that is problem

Comment: @gregg The thing is that during Windows startup it seems that it is not using the correct driver, low resolution, after some seconds the driver is set, so in Windows the driver is correct but I even got a notification as I've just reinstalled the driver, but it is the same prior to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that Windows is booting with the wrong driver,
then switching to the right one.

To stop Windows from switching graphical drivers, see
[my answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672)
to the post
[How do I stop Windows 10 from updating my graphics driver?](https://superuser.com/questions/964475/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-updating-my-graphics-driver)

Ensure that the right driver is installed, before executing the
procedure described in the link.

Comment: What I find odd is that I'm using a fresh Windows install, validated, and a fresh NVIDIA driver. So there should be more ppl with the same problem! Your procedures may be a workaround, but not the solution and not that easy do implement.

Comment: It's not that hard to do, and it's not a workaround since it resolves the conflict between the Windows and NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Googling for *"low resolution screen during boot nvidia windows 10"* makes me suppose it is a 'normal' behaviour, because the graphics driver is not loaded in the memory yet when the system starts up, so the reslution is determined by standard settings. Once the dirver is fully loaded, resolution is adapted to your driver's settings.

Here are some ways you could try to resolve the issue:

1. Check if the speed with which your HDD is accesed to load the driver can be an issue. SSD? HDD?
2. Is there anything at startup blocking the loading of the driver? A cleaning of the registry might help.
3. Maybe in BIOS you can specify a different resolution to use at startup.
4. You might try to change the order in which drivers are loaded at startup. There doesn't seem to be much information available on this, but there's [a microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/specifying-driver-load-order) which might give you a start.

**OLD ANSWER**
The problem probably is not windows, but the bios of your motherboard. If you do not need the iGPU at all, do the following (this should work for ASUS motherboards):
(adapted [from this page](https://www.nicehash.com/blog/post/how-to-disable-onboard-gpu))

- first, make sure your monitor is connected to the GPU, not the motherboard. Then,
- go into bios
- start "advanced" mode (normally f7)
- Navigate to Advanced tab.
- Navigate to System Agent (SA) Configuration.
- Navigate to Graphics Configuration.
- Locate iGPU Multi-Monitor and set it to Disabled.

Comment: It was already disabled. The primary graphics output was set to auto. I've changed it to PCIE, but during boot I still got the same low resolution screen first.

Comment: @Pedro77 See my edit!

Comment: I use windows for decades and this driver loading was never noticeable, I'm using SSD. After each restart Windows also brings a notification of G-Sync display connect, as it was the first time it is recognized. I googled a lot also. Maybe its a bios bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in your driver. Reinstalling it wont work, as it installs the same drivers again (so it if it has a bug, it will still be there)

As you said, reinstalling Windows solved it for a couple of days; well, It could be, that when you reinstalled it, the driver was not the latest version, and after some time, the driver updated; giving you the problem again.

**Solution : Try downgrading your driver version. (eg. from version 5.6.7  to 5.6.6) Downgrade it one version down by downloading the drivers from Google and keep me posted about the result.**

Hope this helps! ❤️

Comment: I have this problem for months and NVIDIA driver is used by a lot of people. I really doubt this is the problem. Anyway I'll check this out later.