# How to prevent Realtek(R) Audio to be installed automatically?

Tags: windows, microphone, realtek-hd-audio

I have an issue with `Realtek(R) Audio`, even if my laptop isn't old (`Lenovo P53s`).
On `Realtek(R) Audio` wired headset and wired earphones has very low mic volume (Bluetooth earphone mic works well, but I don't like to use it, because to cuts off internet sometimes), Laptop's mic array works fine though but I want to use headset's or earphone's mic in order to capture sound from the more distance. I found out that my wired headset's volume is good on `High Definition Audio Device`. My approach to install it was trying to install Realtek drivers (from `Lenovo` website). Its setup asks me to uninstall current Realtek drivers first and then restart the PC to install the new drivers. For some reason I'm failing to install Realtek drivers at that moment (I get some error code like `001`), but the good thing is that I have `High Definition Audio Device` and my mic works well in that state. However, after a few moments I get the notification that PC needs to be restarted to finish setup the device (Realtek). I tried to disable driver installation by hardware ID using [`Disable automatic driver install on Windows 11` and `Disable automatic driver install with Group Policy` methods](https://pureinfotech.com/disable-automatic-driver-install-windows-11/) but they don't seem to be working. How can I block `Realtek Audio` installation after restart or fix low mic volume on it? Thanks.

[Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB6bl.png)

[Device Manager 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnqJQ.png)

[gpedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOZtV.png)

[Installation failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJHak.png)

Edit:

I tried to install Realtek drivers again. After uninstallation and restarting I got the same installation error, but somehow Realtek Audio was installed without restarting itself. It seems that there is even no reliable way to get that High Definition Audio device installed.

Edit 2:

That was my fault because, as you see in the screenshot, I configured Allow not Prevent installation. Now I did everything by steps, but when I turned on the internet, High definition device dissapeared from sound settings and in device manager appeared in Other devices with exclamation mark with error: `The installation of this device is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator`. Any solution for this? I found only that I need to change gpedit settings and it isn't the option in my case. I'm able to solve it by disabling Windows updates. But how can I apply disabling Windows updates only for one device? I tried to enable some setting on gpedit which tells something like "do not install driver updates with windows updates" (don't remember where exactly it is) and also tried to hide all updates which includes `Intel(R)` word using [this tool](https://pureinfotech.com/hide-updates-windows-10/) but it didn't help.

Comment: See especially [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) in the duplicate link.

Comment: 1. In Derive Manager, **disable** the Realtek Audio driver... no need to uninstall. 2. **How** did you uninstall it, before? Through *Programs and features*? 3. Use paragraphs to **organize** your ideas.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for comment. Well, that was my fault because, as you see in the screenshot, I configured `Allow` not `Prevent` installation. Now I did everything by steps, but when I turned on the internet, `High definition device dissapeared from sound settings and in device manager appeared in `Other devices` with exclamation mark with error: `The installation of this device is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator.
` any solution for this? I found only that I need to change gpedit settings and it isn't the optio nin my case.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks. When I disable it in device manager I just have no sound. As I described in post, I uninstalled with Realtek installer.

Comment: @Androider [Edit] your question instead of submitting temporary commentary.

Comment: @Ramhound Already did with expansions.

Comment: @Androider - It had been hours since you last edited the question when I submitted that comment, and even now, you only recently edited the question. Which brings up an entirely different level of feedback, it's unnecessary to indicated you edited your question within the body of the question, as a user anyone can see the changes between two revisions. I was going to inline the screenshots for you, but the state of the question isn't at a point, where I can mark the question as being eligible to be reviewed to be reopened.  The issues that exist (w the ques) are only something you can resolve.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I have a job and studying, so, not much free time I have. About question state you're right, it expanded too much. I probably need to create a new question as I have a different issue now.