# Windows 11 Pro: How to fix warning icon in device manager for some hardware controllers?

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I built a new modern system and included the [Creative AE-9](https://us.creative.com/p/sound-blaster/sound-blaster-ae-9) in it for best audio experience. I installed Windows 11 Pro on my new system and everything was recognized and working nice. I then picked a Windows update KB5019509 which left couple of hardware controller devices in my system unrecognizable. For example, AE-9 digital output was no longer recognized by the system as well as Logitech HD Pro Webcam C902. They show this warning icon in Device Manager:
[image]

I have tried every possible way to fix this but haven't had any success. For example, I tried rolling back that Windows update; also tried uninstalling and re-installing the drivers; or deleting those controllers in Device Manager for Windows to reinstall the drivers. Unfortunately, nothing has worked for me so far.

I also contacted support for those vendors and I am left with two alternatives that I don't like:

1. Reinstall the addon PCI-E hardware card. I don't like fiddling with the hardware installation specially when hardware-wise everything is working.
2. Reinstall Windows 11 Pro, it is a lot of work to get it back to the current state.

**UPDATE 1:**

under Properties for `HD Pro Webcam C920` and `High Definition Audio Device` (AE-9 Digital output) I see:

> Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required
> for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have
> installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might
> be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)

**UPDATE 2:**

Is there a way to get the raw driver files from Creative and Logitech for those hardware controllers? If I could get the raw few driver files I could do `Update driver` and overwrite those drivers with the official ones and be done with it. However, Creative only has a installer that doesn't fix the problem. Likewise Logitech only has the installer of G HUB and not direct access to a zip with the drivers.

**UPDATE 3**

In Device Manager right-click and choosing Update driver, select manually I see the following choices:
[image]

It simply picks the Microsoft one even though the latest from Creative is available 6.0.105.63. How can I block that specific Microsoft `High Definition Audio Device` driver from being picked as default?

Comment: Within the properties of the device what is the exact status of the device? Have you checked the optional updates within Windows Update to determine if a driver can be downloaded? If you no longer have KB5019509 installed then it couldn’t be the cause of your issue

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ramhound! I updated the question.

Comment: So the driver being installed and the device status changing wasn’t connected. The certificate that signed the driver likely expired. Can you confirm?

Comment: Did you install this very recent [driver](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-150/articles/360024849133-Download-HD-Pro-Webcam-C920) from 2022-10-25, marked as compatible with Windows 11?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! the driver should be the official one from Creative but I see a Microsoft driver taking over the device and leading to this 52 error. What also puzzles me is that outside the digital output, the rest of the AE-9 devices are connected to the correct Creative driver and working properly. On the HD Pro Web cam, it should have been the Logitech G HUB driver but again is also a Microsoft one ...

Comment: do you have the "roll back driver" option for either problem device?https://pureinfotech.com/rollback-driver-windows-11/

Comment: @Moab good point thanks! I tried that too without success. It doesn't have a driver to fall back to and keep on picking the faulty Microsoft driver.

Comment: @SkyWalker - You might want to look up the device id within the Windows Update Catalog and see if you can find a more recent driver update yourself and install that, if you are unable to get the OEM driver to install, for whatever reason.  I suspect KB5019509  being installed and the device not working are two separate unrelated events given the code 52 on the device itself.

Answer (score 1):

The right driver needs to be downloaded from Logitech at
[Download - HD Pro Webcam C920](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-150/articles/360024849133-Download-HD-Pro-Webcam-C920).

To fix the problem of Windows auto-updating the driver to a bad one, see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672)
of mine.

Comment: It should be unnecessary to block Windows from updating the driver.  Device drivers are marked as optional updates within Windows Update, the user must be seek and manually select the driver to be installed (at least on currently supported versions of Windows 10) and all version of Windows 11.  How device drivers are installed on currently supported versions of Windows 10 and Windows 11 has changed significantly, the usefulness of Device Managers, is fairly limited on those versions.  It should be enough to use the Logitech installer.

Comment: The theory is beautiful but is not working , I have already tried multiple times running Logitec and Creative installers but uninstalling/reinstalling them doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: If you have blocked all the concerned Microsoft drivers and have installed the correct drivers, then this should work. If it still doesn't work, there might be more drivers to block, or something else is wrong beside the drivers.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work for me, probably because I am on Windows 11 and not 10? anyhow, every time I stop internet, uninstall the driver / device then re-install Creative's driver I see the old Microsoft driver picking up again.

Comment: I wonder if some installed third-party software is doing that. Try it when booting in Safe mode.