# How to uninstall the "LE_WH-H910N (h.ear)" driver on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, headset

How do I uninstall the `LE_WH-H910N (h.ear)` and `LE_WH-H900N (h.ear)` drivers?

When I go device manager and uninstall the `LE_WH-H910N (h.ear)` driver, the `LE_WH-H900N (h.ear)` will instantly show up to replace it, and vice-versa: when I uninstall the `LE_WH-H900N (h.ear)` driver, the `LE_WH-H910N (h.ear)` instantly shows up to replace it, I've tried uninstalling them both in rapid succession like 10 times now, it doesn't work, the other show up to replace the uninstalled one immediately.

How do I uninstall them?
[image: Devices]

Comment: Are your headphones still connected? I assume it automatically installs the drivers when you connect your headphones to make sure they work correctly. Try unpairing your headphones and removing the drivers.

Comment: @Foxyz no, they're not connected. and bluetootoh is disabled when i try to uninstall them.

Comment: https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/03/stop-windows-from-installing-drivers-for-specific-devices/

Comment: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/prevent-automatic-driver-installation-in-windows-10/

Comment: Did you try disabling both devices first? There could also be some related one(s) in `Audio inputs and outputs`.

Comment: Did you also select "Delete the device software for this device" when removing the device? See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

Comment: @Destroy666 No i didn't, and now it's too late to try - i no longer have those devices, and i figured out how to delete them :)

Comment: @harrymc that was not an option, it never asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enable Bluetooth.**

For unknown reasons, removing the drivers while bluetooth is disabled, is futile. Removing the drivers while bluetooth is enabled, works fine  :)  (no idea why)

[image]