# How am I supposed to reinstall gpu drivers when there is no integrated graphics?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu, troubleshooting, integrated-graphics

Ok, So I just got my first desktop pc, And I'm Loving it. There's an major ptoblem tho. After I installed the new gpu drivers almost every game crashes and some games just **crash my whole pc**. It is an gpu **driver problem** and How am I supposed to uninstall it? I mean Im thinking that cuz my *hdmi* cable is connected to the gpu (3070) And After I uninstall the drivers to install it again then there will be no display. Cuz the system **wont recognize the gpu** because I uninstalled the drivers. And I cant just plug the *Hdmi* to the motherboard cuz there is **no integrated graphics**. If the solution is hard then I will just reinstall the **windows 11**. I hope you can understand that whats happening in my mind, Also if there is an method to just uninstall ***directX*** and reinstall it directly then please tell it to me. I hope there is an solution to this.Note: Roll back driver is grayed out, And I installed the driver manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that you will lose all video through the GPU without a GPU driver installed is wrong. Basic functionality, without hardware acceleration, will work if the driver is uninstalled.

Windows 11 has an older NVIDIA Graphics driver integrated and it will be automatically resinstalled, although updating to the most recent driver is generally recommended.

It is not possible to unistall DirectX and install it only, or to use DirectX for meaningful acceleration without a driver. DirectX is an API that allows games to use GPU features for acceleration without having to programed to each and every GPU ever manufactured.

Suggested course of action:

1. Download the latest driver for your GPU from [www.nvidia.com/drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/drivers)
2. Install the newer driver, select the "Custom (Advanced)" installation option, and then the option to "Perform a clean installation"
3. Reboot as required, and again after the installation is completed

Answer (score 0):

You can return to the previous driver version for a device like this:

- Run Device Manager
- Right-click your device and select Properties
- Position to the Driver tab
- Click Roll Back Driver.

If the drivers were updated automatically by Windows (not through your
actions), to block such update see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

Comment: Can't Roll back driver is grayed out. And I installed it manually.

Comment: In this case, you could uninstall the display driver and lose your display, then do a short press on the Power button to shutdown the computer. On reboot Windows will install its own driver. You may afterward, if you want, install another driver version.

Comment: Are you really sure that I wont brick my pc? Do I need to do additional steps like plugging the hdmi to motherboard or something like that?

Comment: I have done it myself and it worked. There is no guarantee when dealing with computers, but it should work. If there is a problem, you could then try other connections. If you wish to be double-protected, [Create a Bootable USB Recovery Drive](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4200-create-recovery-drive-windows-10-a.html) (which is always a good idea to keep in case of future errors).

Comment: Do you have another pc on your network that you can use to remote into the one you are trying to re-install the GPU driver on? I find MSTSC (Microsoft Remote Desktop) will always display graphics regardless of GPU driver being present or not. So you should be able to remote into your PC using MSTSC (Run Menu), type in the IP address of your PC, log in and install the desired driver remotely. NVIDIA drivers under "Custom" has a "Perform Clean Installation" checkbox that can be ticked. This removes the old driver and installs the new all in one go.