# Installation of Drivers Via Programming Language

Tags: windows, drivers, powershell, .net-framework

I have a Driver called X that manages a hardware component A. I would like to remove that drive and replace it with one called Y that also manages the component A.

So far I have been using .NET Framework 6.0, C# Programming Language, along with PNPUtil.exe to install the driver but I think my method is wrong because I have just been doing the following:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "PnPUtil.exe",
                    Arguments = $"-i -a \"{driverFile}\"",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                };
```

This is just installation and the device in the console says it installed but when I go into the Device Management and look up device by driver I do not find my driver Y.
I looking for answer to demonstrate or point to a tutorial on how to do this and if PowerShell can replicate this as well. My OS is Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

You install a driver, but whether it's used for a device
is depended upon the driver's definition in its `.inf` file.

Note that if you install an older driver, Windows may
automatically update it to a newer version.
To block that update see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672).

The Windows command for installing drivers is
[PnPUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-command-syntax),
using the command:

```
pnputil -i -a <driverinf>
```

If the INF to install has a `DefaultInstall` section,
it can also be installed with this command:

```
rundll32 advpack.dll,LaunchINFSection <PathTo>\name.inf,,1
```

If a `DefaultInstall` section is not present, then you need to
find which install-section to call instead using the command:

```
rundll32 advpack.dll,LaunchINFSection <PathTo>\name.inf,<InstallSection>,1
```

Sources:

- [Installing a driver (.inf) file from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496847/installing-a-driver-inf-file-from-command-line)
- [How can I install a .inf file from the command line?](https://msfn.org/board/topic/104891-how-can-i-install-a-inf-file-from-the-command-line/)
- [LaunchINFSectionEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768006(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Note: For C# or .Net programming questions, you can ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).